# Not able to find Created subscription under local Subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

I want to create SQL Replication. So I have created Local Publication. It was Successful. Later I created Local Subscription for that Publication. After clicking on Finish Button, It said creation was Successful.
I can see the created Subscription under publication, But I am not able to see it under Local Subscriptions folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Just creating the publication and an associated subscription won't necessarily display the subscription in the Local Subscriptions folder - not until the relevant agent has replicated data from source to destination. So for example, if a subscription subscribes to a transactional publication, you would need to run at least the Snapshot Agent to get a snapshot from source in order to populate your destination database. (Optionally run the Log Reader Agent to get transactions subsequent to the snapshot). Then you should see an entry in the Local Subscriptions folder. It may take some time if a large amount of data is being replicated. If a subscription is configured to rely on a PUSH from source, then that subscription entry in the Local Subscriptions folder will appear slightly faded to differentiate it from PULL subscriptions.